# Ionic 3. Unable to load page via devApp

Tags: ionic-framework, mobile, ionic-devapp

I'm a first time using Ionic 3 framework to create cross-mobile native application.

I had some problem when I test program with devApp application.

On browser it runs well, but on mobile shows error:

> Unable to load page. The request time out.

[image]

Does somebody know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This could be triggered by so many reasons like bad code, network issues and so on

So I suggest you to:

- Close your Devapp completly
- Disconnect from Wifi
- Close App in your browser
- do a fresh new `ionic serve -c`
- Start DevApp again
- Connect to Wifi again
- Start your App on Device

If this doesnt work you need to show us your code from `app.component.ts` and `index.html` and also your `ionic info`

Answer (score 0):

Ionic devApp connects to your app using device internal ip on the same router. It might change everytime you connect.

Find the internal ip (ubuntu: `ifconfig -a`) and manually enter the ip and port using the option **manually enter address** in the sidebar.